# How to get field value in Wordpress shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I try to get field value in shortcode. But it is not work.
How can I do it?
**"audio_url"** is field meta name.

```
<?php
$audio_source = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audio_url',true);

echo do_shortcode('
[zoomsounds_player config="motionplayer" source="{$audio_source}"]
');

?>
```

Comment: What is happening?  Have you confirmed that `$audio_source` is the expected value?

Answer (score 1):

If `$audio_source` is the expected value... looks like you need to swap your quotes to use PHP Variable Interpolation like so:

```
<?php
$audio_source = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audio_url',true);

echo do_shortcode("[zoomsounds_player config='motionplayer' source='{$audio_source}']");

?>
```

Comment: I already found a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$audio_source = get_field('audio_url');
if ($audio_source) {
    echo do_shortcode('[zoomsounds_player config="motionplayer" source="'
        . $audio_source . '"]');
}
```